# Flutter Lost connection to device

Tags: ios, flutter

I use Iphone 11 emulator. I hit run button and got this:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           37.0s
Waiting for iPhone 11 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65405/L1H3N-Q0JFU=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
Lost connection to device.
```

It opens the app and shut down immediately.
I performed `flutter clean` but it's not working.
This is my `flutter doctor`":

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-2.0.pre.98, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Answer (score 9):

When I tried to run the app from the XCode, it showed me the actual error. I was missing the google Ad Identifier inside the Info.plist file. Once I added it, it started working fine.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helped me to solve my problem. In my case I needed to add apiKey parameter in FirebaseOptions and only xCode show the error

Comment: 4 days of torture finally resolved with this simple answer.